# How do you use mirror and shade smooth at the same time?

Tags: mirror, smooth

I'm designing half of an object and then using the mirror tool to make the other half. When I try to smooth the design using the shade smoot tool it leaves a large divot along where the two halves meet. I have tried the other shade tools and they don't work as well as shade smooth for me. How do I stop the divot from happening?

Comment: Make sure clipping is on in the mirror modifier

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  If my answer below doesn't help then a few more details could be useful, such as a screenshot that shows the issue and your Mirror modifier settings.  Also, the Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files, it's often a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Answers suggest clipping, but also make sure the mirror modifier is before (on top) of the subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: @rafe For the _Shade Smooth_ option there is no order in the modifiers necessary. And the _Subdivision Surface_ can be on top of the _Mirror_ modifier, the geometry might look different but it would still be shaded smooth - as long as the "Merge" option is enabled in the _Mirror_ modifier.

Comment: In addition to the solutions mentioned before - I would recommend on checking any accidental geometry inside the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

If what you're describing is similar to the above graphic then Shade Smooth is probably not causing the problem.  Either you don't have Clipping and/or Merge checked, or your model has vertices that should be zero on the X axis but aren't quite there.